# PHP to JQUERY - Accessing JSON Elements

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sending the following from PHP to JSON

```
 print json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'status' => array('username' => 'valid', 'password' => 'valid', 'token' => $tokenhash)));
```

I can access success in JQUERY like this for example:

```
        function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
```

How can I access token?
I tried alert(data.success.token);
Note: just using alert to see if I can hook into the required value.

Is there a syntax similar to data.success that I can use for token?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it `data.status.token` that you are looking for ?

Comment: ya... works great... thx... now I see it it's obvious... will tick the answer once the time factor allows... cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

`data.success` is just grabbing the success key from your array. Looks like you want `data.status.token`.